# Compare frequencies of categorical events between two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

Selectively rendered animations (parts were rendered with higher quality than the rest) were shown to participants of an experiment. The animations were either with or without sound. Then the participants were given two stills of the animation, one selectively rendered like the before seen animation and the other one with the same rendering quality over the whole imagery, and had to decide which one was a still of the before seen animation. The hypothesis is that it would be more difficult for subjects to notice rendering quality variations in the presence of sound than while watching silent animations.

The collected answers could be either true or false and should be enough to find a correlation between the auditory background and the perceived rendering quality.

Which method could be used for the statistical analysis of the results? A goal is to compare the frequencies of categorical events (true/false) between two groups (the ones watching the animation with sound/the ones watching the animation without sound).

Comment: For each image, shown once with sound, once without sound (or really that applies to the animation) there is given an answer, which is wrong (false) or correct (true).  How was the design?   How many persons?  The same images and questions/stils given to each person, or different animations/stills to each of the persons? Most importantly, the two queations(with/without sound) from one animation were given to each person, or each person only one of the questions? Was the order of the questions randomized?  As you see, we need better information.  Please edit that information into the question!